# How to only slideDown/Up when specific element does not have error class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

With the following code I slide the sibling div up and down.

But now I only want to allow this when the element in it is not assigned to an error class.

**jQuery**

```
$('input').on('focus blur', function(e){
    $(this).siblings('div')[e.type === 'focus' ? 'slideDown' : 'slideUp']('fast');
})
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="input">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text">
    <div>
        <div class="addition error">Input error 1</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="input">
    <label>Rest</label>
    <input type="text">
    <div>
        <div class="addition error">Input error 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="input">
    <label>Rest</label>
    <input type="text">
    <!-- So only this should be able to slide -->
    <div>
        <div class="addition">Input addition 1</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check for the class inside the event handler

```
$('input').on('focus blur', function(e){
    if ( $(this).closest('.input').find('.error').length === 0)
        $(this).siblings('div')[e.type === 'focus' ? 'slideDown' : 'slideUp']('fast');
});
```

Comment: Sorry to disturb, but I am curious to learn. I would like to understand why your solution is better?

Comment: Not sure if it's better, they both seem to work, @web-tiki added a fiddle that shows his works as well, but it seems to animate the `.addition` element, not the wrapping noname div, if that matters ?

Answer (score 2):

How about this ?

```
$('input').on('focus blur', function(e){
    $(this).siblings('div').children().not('.error')[e.type === 'focus' ? 'slideDown' : 'slideUp']('fast');
})
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/8TZKk/6/)**

Comment: Omg just saw the Evil Genius @adeneo wrote an answer too I am condemned!